# NLog Colored Console

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, console, nlog

I am using NLog to log errors. Here is the Config code

```
<target name="console" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" >
      <target  xsi:type="ColoredConsole"  layout="${longdate:padding=-10}${callsite:className=false:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=false} | ${message}" >
         <highlight-row condition="level >= LogLevel.Info" foregroundColor="Green" backgroundColor="NoChange"/> 
      </target>
    </target>
```

I have a custom property set on the log event like

```
private LogEventInfo GetLogEvent(string loggerName, LogLevel level, string message, ConsoleColor color)
        {
    var logEvent = new LogEventInfo(level, loggerName, message);

                logEvent.Properties["color"] = color;// color= any console color
}
```

and this sets the "color" property.(lets say "Red" here)

and I am trying to use this "color" property in the target like

```
 <highlight-row condition="equals('${color}','Red')" foregroundColor="Red" backgroundColor="NoChange"/>
```

this dosent work and I tried

```
<highlight-row condition="equals('${event-context:item=color}','Red')" foregroundColor="Red" backgroundColor="NoChange"/>
```

but no luck.

Am I missing something or is there a better way of doing this? Can we use Layout renderers in this case? If yes how do we implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, since you are storing values in `LogEventInfo.Properties`, you should be using your second configuration example, which gets the value from `event-context`.

I have not used the `ColoredConsoleTarget`, so take this as a suggestion, not as something that I know for a fact will work.

I suspect that the NLog `Condition` object does not know about the `ConsoleOutputColor` enum.  So, when you store a `ConsoleOutputColor` enum value in `LogEventInfo.Properties`, the `Condition` does not know that `'Red'` (in the condition) refers to `ConsoleOutputColor.Red`.  I have two suggestions:

First option: store the string value of the `ConsoleOutputColor` in `LogEventInfo.Properties`.  Using `ToColor` might be sufficient.  Something like this:

```
var logEvent = new LogEventInfo(level, loggerName, message);
logEvent.Properties["color"] = color.ToString();
```

Then, in your `Condition`, you should be able to compare against the `ConsoleOutputColor` string values (what you have in your configuration might be right, if you store the color name string as I suggested).

If that doesn't work, you could try...

Second option: store the `ConsoleOutputColor` value in `LogEventInfo.Properties`, as you are doing now, but change your condition in the config file to compare the "color" from event-context to the numeric value of the `ConsoleOutputColor` values.  Something like this (I have not tried this so I don't know for sure that it is correct):

```
<highlight-row condition="equals('${event-context:item=color}','12')" foregroundColor="Red" backgroundColor="NoChange"/>
```

(In the `ConsoleOutputColor` enum, `Red` is `12`).